# enzyme: TypeError: Adapter is not a constructor

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

Hi I was trying to test the react application With enzyme, But it throws an error **TypeError: Adapter is not a constructor**  , Any Idea

This is my test file

> ```
> import ProductRow from '../product_row';
> import React from 'react';
> // import { mount } from 'enzyme';
> import * as enzyme from 'enzyme';
> import * as Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';
> enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });
>
> test('TodoComponent renders the text inside it', () => {
>   const wrapper = enzyme.mount(
>     <ProductRow  item={{}} quickView={[]}
>       productPage={''}
>       count={0}
>       numberOfColumns={0}
>       title={'title'}
>       taxonomies={{}}
>       excerpt={'excerpt'}
>     />
>   );
> });
> ```
>
> TypeError: Adapter is not a constructor

Answer (score 48, accepted):

I don't think `import *` works as expected when importing a module with a default export, this should work:

```
import Enzyme from 'enzyme'
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16'

Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() })
```

BTW. you can put the above in a file and reference it in your Jest settings so you don't have to add this to every test:

```
setupFiles: ['<rootDir>/tools/jest/setup-react-adapter.js'],
```

Comment: I am using following code and getting same error.
import Enzyme from 'enzyme'
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-preact-pure';
Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

Answer (score 10):

For TypeScript:

```
import { configure } from 'enzyme';
import * as ReactSixteenAdapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';
const adapter = ReactSixteenAdapter as any;
configure({ adapter: new adapter.default() });
```

Comment: Thanks I've been looking for this

Answer (score 8):

You need to use the import like this:

```
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';
```

This way: **(import * as Adapter from ...)** returns a message "TypeError: Adapter is not a constructor."

Answer (score 1):

In case you are using Typescript with the `esModuleInterop` option enabled, you'll need this:

```
import { configure} from 'enzyme';
import * as ReactSixteenAdapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';
configure({ adapter: new (ReactSixteenAdapter as any)() });
```